# Python - Efficiently building a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to build a dict(dict(dict())) out of multiple files, which are stored in different numbered directories, i.e.

```
/data/server01/datafile01.dat
/data/server01/datafile02.dat
...
/data/server02/datafile01.dat
/data/server02/datafile02.dat
...
/data/server86/datafile01.dat
...
/data/server86/datafile99.dat
```

I have a couple problems at the moment:

1. Switching between directories

I know that I have 86 servers, but the number of files per server may vary. I am using:

```
for i in range(1,86):
    basedir='/data/server%02d' % i
    for file in glob.glob(basedir+'*.dat'):
        Do reading and sorting here
```

but I cant seem to switch between the directories properly. It just sits in the first one and gets stuck it seems when there are no files in the directory

1. Checking if key already exists

I would like to have a function that somehow checks if a key is already present or not, and in case it isnt creates that key and certain subkeys, since one cant define dict[Key1][Subkey1][Subsubkey1]=value

BTW i am using Python 2.6.6

Comment: You are missing a `/` between `basedir` and your glob.

Comment: You should use `os.path.join` to build paths.

Comment: Also don't shadow the builtin `file`.

Comment: Are your two questions related?

Comment: They came up in the same code. I am just trying not to open too many threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Björn helped with the [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) half of your question.  His suggestion should get you very close to where you want to be in terms of the default value for keys that do not yet exist.

The best tool for walking a directory and looking at files is [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk).  You can combine the directory and filename names that you get from it with [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to find the files you are interested in.  Something like this:

```
import os

data_path = '/data'

# option 1 using nested list comprehensions**
data_files = (os.path.join(root,f) for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(data_path)
                                   for f in files)   # can use [] instead of ()

# option 2 using nested for loops
data_files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_path):
    for f in files:
        data_files.append(os.path.join(root, f))

for data_file in data_files:
    # ... process data_file ...
```

**Docs for [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 2):

I can't help you with your first problem, but the second one can be solved by using a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). This is a dictionary that has a function that is called to generate a value when a requested key did not exist. Using `lambda` you can nest them:

```
>>> your_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))
>>> your_dict[1][2][3]
0
```

Comment: For infinite nesting you can use `def default(): return defaultdict(default)`. Recursion!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming these 'directories' are remotely mounted shares?

Couple of things:

1. I'd use `os.path.join` instead of `'basedir' + '*.dat'`
2. For FS related stuff I've had very good results parallelizing the computation using
   multiprocessing.Pool to get around those times where a remote fs might be extremely slow and hold up the whole process.

   ```
   import os
   import glob
   import multiprocessing as mp

   def processDir(path):
       results = {} 
       for file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(path,'*.dat')):
            results.update(add to the results here)
       return results

   dirpaths = ['/data/server%02d'%i for i in range(1,87)]
   _results = mp.Pool(8).map(processDir,dirpaths)
   results  = combine _results here...
   ```

For your dict-related problems, use `defaultdict`, as mentioned in the other answers, or even your own dict subclass, or function?

```
def addresult(results,key,subkey,subsubkey,value):
    if key not in results:
        results[key] = {}
    if subkey not in results[key]:
        results[key][subkey] = {}
    if subsubkey not in results[key][subkey]:
        results[key][subkey][subsubkey] = value
```

There are almost certainly more efficient ways to accomplish this, but that's a start.